# Annotation's Title and Subtitle in detail view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I have a detail view that is pushed from a map.  I am trying to get the title and subtitle from the annotation to show in the detail view.  I can get the title to show in the Navigation bar, but I cannot get them to show up as UILabels.  I have UILabels in my interface builder for the MapDetailInfo all connected to the "name" and "address", but they will not fill when the view is pushed.  Here is my code:

In My Map View Controller

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
   MapDetailInfo *abc = [[MapDetailInfo alloc]init];

   abc.title = view.annotation.title;


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:abc animated:YES];



nameText.text = view.annotation.title;
addressText.text = view.annotation.subtitle;

}
```

In My Detail View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

BusinessListingsPart3ViewController *blv = [[BusinessListingsPart3ViewController alloc] init];

name.text = blv.nameText.text;
address.text = blv.addressText.text;
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `name` and `address` are not instantiated at this time. Their values will be `nil`.

Declare `nameText` and `addressText` as properties, set them in this method and then later update the labels in the `viewDidLoad` method.

---

**MapDetailInfo.h**

```
@interface MapDetailInfo: .... {
    NSString * nameText;
    NSString * addressText;

    ....
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * nameText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * addressText;

....
```

---

**MapDetailInfo.m**

```
@implementation MapDetailInfo

@synthesize nameText;
@synthesize addressText;

....
```

---

In the current method `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryTapped:`, replace

```
abc.name.text= view.annotation.title;
abc.address.text = view.annotation.subtitle;
```

with

```
abc.nameText = view.annotation.title;
abc.addressText = view.annotation.subtitle;
```

And in `MapDetailInfo`'s `viewDidLoad` method, add

```
self.name.text = nameText;
self.address.text = addressText;
```

Comment: Already tried moving those below pushing the view controller.  No success.

Comment: Updated the answer. Also make sure you have set your interface connections properly.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do.. it came up with a few errors... I was able to get rid of the errors by editing my code (see above I edited my code as well).  The Labels are still showing blank. I double check to make sure I had them connected correctly as well.

Comment: The changes are not in the way I intended. Added more code to be more specific. As of now, the problem with the code you've added is that you are creating a new instance of `BusinessListingsPart3ViewController` where the properties you are accessing are `nil`.